# Multiple items in MonTouch.Dialog section header

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Based on Miguel's response to another question (see below) I was able to get a label in my section header. But I'm looking to take it a little further with 3 lines of text.  My first thought is instead of creating the header with a single label, is there a way to create it with a uiview where inside that view you can place whatever items you want?

*Section headers and footers can either be specified as strings or UIViews, there is sadly, nothing in between.*

*If you want to have custom headers/views, you would need to create a UILabel and use that in your constructor to the Section type (only available for the Elements API).*

*Something like:*

```
    var header = new UILabel (new RectangleF (0, 0, 320, 48)){
        Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (22),
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red
    }

    new Section(header, footer) {
        ...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

The parameters to the Section constructor are either two strings of text, or two UIViews.   In the sample above you merely created a UIView of type UILabel, but it could be anything you want, with as many subviews as you want or need.